Why is this Overflow: hidden; does not work in safari? And what is the way to fix it without loosing the scroll position?


// Function to handle opening the search
window.handleCustomSearchOpen = function () {
  document.body.classList.toggle('opensearchpanel')
};
.opensearchpanel {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
<body>
  <button onclick="handleCustomSearchOpen()">Search</button>
</body>



On mobile, I have a search bar and when it open, it adds a class "opensearchpanel". On which I am using overflow: hidden; and it is working as expected in chrome and android by fixing the scroll. But in safari it is not working and to fix it I added
It fixed the scroll issue but now by added it I am loosing the scroll position, on the position where user was, It scrolls the screen to the top and I don't want that. I want that where ever the user was should be at it's place on the screen and the screen should freeze meaning that It should not scroll until the search is closed.
Have also used position: relative; instead of fixed

Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre] so the readers can run and debug.

Done, It is just a body on which there is class "opensearchpanel"

That is not a [mre], how do you add the class "opensearchpanel" with HTML and CSS only?

Please show us the code that works on browsers other than Safari.

I am working on the app of my company, I don't have the access to the full code. THere is just a button on which when user click, it adds the class on the body i.e openseachpanel. And the CSS on this class is what I provided. it is woking fine on chrome but not on safari.

Your snippet is broken, it seems you put HTML and JS into the CSS field... Also I think without some element with the class and without some button to open the search panel and probably some placeholder text we won't see anything happening. When we click "Run code snippet", we should see the behavior happening that you described. Please update your snippet to showcase the problem reproducibly.
